# How to clean up almost-symmetrical vertices?

Tags: mesh, mirror

I'm working with a low poly game model, and I need to fix some vertices that are symmetric by design, but somehow were made imperceptibly asymmetric by rounding error or something.

I need to fix that asymmetry so I can use tools like Select Mirror and so I have the ability to mirror shape keys.

The mesh has some intentionally asymmetric aspects in texture mapping and geometry, so I can't just delete half the model and apply a mirror modifier. Also the model is rigged and I don't want to lose the bone weights.

Is there a way to broadly fix the asymmetric vertex positions in a vertex selection?

The only way I've found to fix it by hand only works with one vertex pair at a time:

- Select both vertices
- Hit <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> to eliminate Y+Z variation.
- Set the median X coordinate to 0 in the Transform Properties

This works for single vertices, but I need to clean up 562 such verts, so doing it one at a time is out of the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'Snap to Symmetry' under Mesh in Edit mode should do it.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/symmetry.html

'Symmetrize' on the same menu may also help, but note that it is quite destructive.

Comment: My man! Works like a charm.

Comment: That link is broken, I think this is the right one. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/symmetry.html#snap-to-symmetry